# Ajax request not going through

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I m working on a project and this is my code according to my research this should go through but its not

Can some please have a look at this

```
function check_address1(){
        var data = {
            'full_name1' : jQuery('#full_name1').val(),
            'street1' : jQuery('#street1').val(),
            'street21' : jQuery('#street21').val(),
            'city1' : jQuery('#city1').val(),
            'county1' : jQuery('#county1').val(),
            'postcode1' : jQuery('#postcode1').val(),
            'country1' : jQuery('#country1').val(),
        };
    jQuery,ajax({
             url : '/project/admin/parsers/check_address1.php',
             method : 'post',
             data : data,
             success : function(data){
                if(data != 'good'){
                    Query('#payment-errors').html(data);
                }
                if (data == 'good') {
                    jQuery('#payment-errors').html("");
                    jQuery('#step1').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#step2').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#step3').css("display",'block');
                    jQuery('#next_button').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#take1').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#take2').css("display",'inline-block');
                    jQuery('#next_button').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#next_button1').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#checkout_button')css("display",'inline-block');
                    jQuery('#checkoutModalLabel').html("Enter your card details")

                }
             },
             error : function(){alert("Something Went Wrong");},
    });
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: should that be `jQuery.ajax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code

1. `jQuery,ajax({` should be `jQuery.ajax({`
2. `Query('#payment-errors').html(data);` should be `jQuery('#payment-errors').html(data);`
3. missing `.` in `jQuery('#checkout_button')css("display",'inline-block');`

Here is correct code

```
function check_address1(){
        var data = {
            'full_name1' : jQuery('#full_name1').val(),
            'street1' : jQuery('#street1').val(),
            'street21' : jQuery('#street21').val(),
            'city1' : jQuery('#city1').val(),
            'county1' : jQuery('#county1').val(),
            'postcode1' : jQuery('#postcode1').val(),
            'country1' : jQuery('#country1').val(),
        };
    jQuery.ajax({
             url : '/project/admin/parsers/check_address1.php',
             method : 'post',
             data : data,
             success : function(data){
                if(data != 'good'){
                    jQuery('#payment-errors').html(data);
                }
                if (data == 'good') {
                    jQuery('#payment-errors').html("");
                    jQuery('#step1').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#step2').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#step3').css("display",'block');
                    jQuery('#next_button').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#take1').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#take2').css("display",'inline-block');
                    jQuery('#next_button').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#next_button1').css("display",'none');
                    jQuery('#checkout_button').css("display",'inline-block');
                    jQuery('#checkoutModalLabel').html("Enter your card details")

                }
             },
             error : function(){alert("Something Went Wrong");},
    });
    }
```

Comment: Yeh sure its saying you have to wait 15 minutes to accept